# How do I find all the newest patents that reference the following patent from 1962: US3018134

Tags: prior-art, us3018134

In reference to the patent: [US3018134](https://www.google.com/patents/US3018134)

Where can I go to find newer patents that have references to a given patent number?

Answer (score 2):

Google does a pretty good job of identifying forward citations.  See https://www.google.com/patents/US3018134#forward-citations for the patent you identified.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section of the page you linked which provides that information. Google patents applies the section "referenced by" on its page for every patent publication and patent. There is a link to that section in the gray box at the top right of those pages.

In the case of the patent you listed, it's the "referenced by (6)" in:

"Patent Citations (6), Referenced by (6), Classifications (5)"

It is the second to last section on that page. Specific to this reference, here is the link to the anchor on that page that brings that section to the top of the browser window:

https://www.google.com/patents/US3018134#forward-citations

I hope that helped. 
The patent office would love to do this on the paper versions of the issued patents, but it is very difficult to find every printed copy and mark it up when someone else's freshly printed patent or patent publication makes a reference to that document. So they leave it to Google instead. ;-)